# using @implementation creates "instance method conflict" warnings in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

In my iOS application I have a 5 view controllers that all deal with the same feature (groups).  These view controllers can be pushed on top of eachother in a few different configurations.  I made a file called GroupViewHelper.h which uses @implementation to provide some functions for the groups feature.  The functions look through the view controller stack and send a "refresh" message to a view controller of a specific type.  The file looks like this:

```
@implementation UIViewController (GroupViewHelper)
- (void) refreshManageGroupsParent
{
   // ...
}

- (void) refreshGroupDetailsParent
{
   // ...
}
@end
```

My code works great and everything behaves as expected, but I get 14 warnings that are all very similar to this at build time:

```
ld: warning: instance method 'refreshGroupDetailsParent' in category from /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ayshzmsyeabbgqbbnbiixjhdmqgs/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp-dev.build/Objects-normal/i386/GroupMembersController.o conflicts with same method from another category
```

I think I'm getting this because I'm using a .H which is included in multiple places, but how do I correctly use @implementation in this situation?

Comment: What are each of your view controllers (e.g. GroupMembersController) subclasses of? UIViewController?

Comment: They are all subclases of something we call a BaseViewController, however this is used for every view controller in the project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I think I'm getting this because I'm using a .H which is included in multiple places

Well, sort of, but the real problem is that you've put the `@implementation` in the `.h` file in the first place. If you only included that `.h` file in one place, you would get away with it—but it would still not be the right way to do it.

> but how do I correctly use @implementation in this situation?

Put it in a file called `GroupViewHelper.m`, and add that file to your project's sources, and put the `@interface` in `GroupViewHelper.h`.

Or, ideally, call them `UIViewController+GroupViewHelper.m` and `UIViewController+GroupViewHelper.h`, because that's the idiomatic way to name category files. (And if you use Xcode's "New File…" menu item to create a new Objective-C category file, that's what it will give you.)

In other words, interfaces and implementations for categories on existing classes work exactly the same as interfaces and implementations for new classes.

Comment: works great! thanks so much.  I totally should have known this

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered exactly this issue. I had imported a reference to a header file, on a .m page.  However, it also contained a reference to another header file, which contained a reference to another header file - that also referenced the conflicted header file. So indirectly the same header file was imported twice, causing the error.

In my case, the .m file did not need this reference. I was able to delete it, removing the error. My advice is check the files where you have included a reference to the offending header file, and verify that it actually is required.